# Why does sourceforge's mercurial view think I am anonymous?

Tags: mercurial, sourceforge

I'm using Mercurial for a sourceforge project, and every time I commit it lists me as being anonymous on the project feed. I am using mercurial through the Eclipse Mercurial plugin from http://bitbucket.org/mercurialeclipse/. What settings do I need to mess with for SourceForge to know who I am when I push my commits?

Mercurial knows my user name, just sourceforge isn't identifying that with my sourceforge user. I have no problem using the command line version of mercurial, in fact I was using this for a while and I still had the same problem.

The commits are accurately labeled based on my username in .hgrc, just sourceforge doesn't identify me properly.

Edit, if you want to see the fledgling project that my friend and I are working on to see the symptoms I am trying to describe, it is here https://sourceforge.net/projects/silversaga/

Comment: Got a link to your sourceforge page?

Comment: The revision link shows an author: http://silversaga.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/silversaga/rev/11 -- that looks OK, right?  Also the summary page: http://silversaga.hg.sourceforge.net/hgweb/silversaga/summary  -- maybe the front page is a sourceforge glitch?

Comment: Is this working for anyone else? These people seem to be rather hg-savvy, but it says "anonymous", too: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gwsmhg/. Maybe you should open a ticket with sourceforge.

Comment: ditto http://sourceforge.net/projects/jubler/ - 900+ commits, all "anonymous" on the front page.

Comment: hmm... maybe there is something to be said there. I will try and file a ticket. I was thinking that there was something special to set the username to that would trigger SourceForge into associating an account.

Comment: Could we rename the title of this question to something more relevant to the question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I filed a [ticket for this issue](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/sourceforge/ticket/2274). It has now been resolved. For anyone interested, it was a bug in SourceForge, and has now been fixed.

From the comment on the ticket detailing the fix.

> Please ensure that your hgrc has a
>   line similar to:
>
> ```
> [ui]
> username = Your Name <username@users.sourceforge.net
> ```

Answer (score 3):

You can set your username in ~/.hgrc with the following lines:

```
[ui]
username = My Name <myname@mydomain>
```

This page has a screenshot of a prefernces windows where you can set this in Eclipse:

- [Mercurial from Eclipse](http://www.aventinesolutions.nl/mediawiki/index.php/Quick_Tip:_Getting_Started_with_Mercurial#Mercurial_from_Eclipse)

Comment: I have done this, and when I click through to the real mercurial view on SourceForge, it shows this. It is just on the main page that it lists me as Anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the mercurial user and sourceforge username are the same? If not, it may be a case of them not matching up. They way you describe it sounds like they are though. Have you tried appending @sourceforge.net or other permutations? I've never used sourceforge myself so I have no idea if something like that even makes sense.

Otherwise I'd suggest asking sourceforge directly and peruse their faq/help, as it sounds like an issue specific to their setup of mercurial. I had a similar issue on bitbucket.org, where I was committing under my local username "matt" whereas my bitbucket username is different. Then they'd link to that user in the changelog even though they don't have access to the project. All I had to do was change the name listed in the eclipse settings and all is well now.